# What happens when %d format specifer is used in scanf to read a character from keyboard?

Tags: c, io, character, scanf, format-specifiers

I'm new to C programming language and I'm trying to learn the behavior of some simple snippets like the one mentioned below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("The entered number is:%d",number);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine when scanf() function reads decimal numbers from keyboard. However when I deliberately enter alphabets, I get output as 0 and when I enter any other characters, I get the output as 53. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: You should not only look at `number` but also on the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

%d is for any number of decimal digits (0-9). And for strange behavior you need to check the return value of scanf function

Here is the exact documentation extract from scanf

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading
>   error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while
>   reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either
>   happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.
>
> If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the
>   function sets errno to EILSEQ.

So, you need to check the return value of scanf function to find out whether the scanf has successfully filled all required items.

Here is a snip of code which will do such error checking

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number;
    int ret;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    ret = scanf("%d",&number);
    if(ret == 1){ // number of expected items to be filled; in your case 1
        printf("The entered number is:%d\n",number);         
    }else{
       printf("Invalid Input\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The %d character means that it expects a decimal number, note this is not a floating point number but a whole number. If you want to put characters in there use %c.

Answer (score 0):

> "*What happens when `%d` format specifer is used in `scanf()` to read a character from keyboard?*"

The actual C standard (C18), Section 7.21.6.2/10 - "The fscanf function" states:

> "*If the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this condition is a matching failure.*"

Thus, the execution of the directive in your provided case shall be failed as you entered a character and no value should have been written into `number` from that particular `scanf()` call.

Always check the return value of `scanf()` which indicates how many input items were assigned successfully or otherwise is `EOF` if an input failure occured before the first conversion has completed.

---

> *"However when I deliberately enter alphabets, I get output as 0 and when I enter any other characters, I get the output as 53. Can someone please explain why this is happening?"*

The reason why it prints out arbitrary numbers is because you did not initialized `number` with any value:

```
int number;
```

Since `number` is an object of the storage-class `auto` by default, it contains a random garbage value, which is then later printed by `printf()`. It has nothing to do with the `scanf()` call as it is.

Thus, if you would initialize `number` with a valid value at its definition like f.e. `int number = 24;` I´m pretty sure the output of the program will be `24` when input characters.